# Android Text Views overflowing and blocking each other out

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-constraintlayout

I am having issues with 2 text views next to each other in a constraint layout. One is a title and one is a dummy "description" and the description ends up displaying off the right edge of the screen and also pushing the title off the left edge of the screen. What am I getting wrong with the layout, the description text needs to do more linebreaks to give the title and itself space to fit within the screen.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fillerContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fillerContent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

edit 1: This view is an item in a recyclerlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is cause by a miss understood on the way that constraints layout work but more important like the attributes of width and height must be used to had a more responsive layout.

When you are using constraints layouts the ideal approach is that views attributes  `width` and `height` has been set as `0dp`, meaning that they will grow respecting the available space and the constraints assigned.

Here is a example of two approaches:

**1. You could set the `width` to `0dp`:**

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fillerContent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="DESCRIPTION"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fillerContent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

**2. Or the equivalent with a little refactor:**

```
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fillerContent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Title "
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `wrap_content`s in a chained `ConstraintLayout`. Judging by the layout, only the `label` needs to be at actual width, and `fillerContent` must take whatever space it can get horizontally. So, you can change the width like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fillerContent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>
```

Set the filler `layout_width` to `0dp`, and it should work.